# Share local files over the internet on Linux?

Tags: linux, webserver, media

I have 30+GB of video files, which I'd like to share with a friend overseas. I have xampp, installed on Xubuntu 12.10 in /opt/lampp/, and the drive containing the video files is on /mnt/MEDIA/. How to set-up apache or maybe another web-server to provide streaming option for his media player (I dont' want to make him download the files). I'm not sure if he's gonna use VLC or GOM Player, but it doesn't matter, he'll use whatever I tell him :)

Comment: A simple webpage with a link to the media file should be enough.

Comment: You mean `file:///` ? If so, it doesn't work in most browsers due to security.

Comment: No, I mean HTML with `<a href="/path/to/file/">file</a>"`

Comment: This only works if `/path/to/file/` is a subfolder/subfile of /opt/lampp/htdocs

Comment: That depends on the way you have set your webserver up, but you should be able to make it work if you make a link (`ln -s /path/to/file/foo.avi link_to_foo.avi`) to the media file and then point the HTML page to that link: `<a href="link_to_foo.avi">file</a>"`.

Comment: Can you explain this a bit more detailed, please? And is this gonna mess up my other projects in htdocs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the simplest way, just make links to your media files and make an HTML page that points to them:

1. Make a link to each of the files you want to share in a directory that is configured to be accessible (`htdocs` for example)

   ```
   find /media/videos -name *avi -o -name *mpg -o -name *mpeg -o -name *mp4  \
     -exec ln -s {} +
   ```
2. Make a simple HTML page with hyperlinks to each of these files

   ```
   echo "<html><body><ul>" > media.html
   for i in *avi *mpg *mpeg *mp4; do if [ -e "$i" ]; then 
     echo "<li><a href=\"$i\">$i</a>" >> media.html
   fi; done
   echo "</ul></body></html>" >> media.html
   ```
3. Point your browser to `music.html` and click one of the files.

Comment: Yep, works like charm :) I even can make my own UI now :) I really appreciate your help! :)